# how to memoize http request page number in react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

how can i fetchMagazineListDetail function arugment memoizing when i call request second time if already
this argument is exist i dont want sent the request.

```
export const fetchMagazineListDetail = (id, paginate) => {
     return dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchMagazineListDetailBegin());
         fetch(`http://localhost:3003/magazine/${paginate}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            if(res.error) {
                throw(res.error);
            }
            dispatch(fetchMagazineListDetailSuccess(res));
            return res;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(fetchMagazineListDetailError(error));
        })
    }
}

Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can group the action and not dispatch it when it was already dispatched. Depending on the cache you can keep result during render, during app active or in local storage:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { createSelector } = Reselect;
const { useEffect, useMemo, useState } = React;
const { produce } = immer;

//group promise returning function
const createGroup = (cache) => (
  fn,
  getKey = (...x) => JSON.stringify(x)
) => (...args) => {
  const key = getKey(args);
  let result = cache.get(key);
  if (result) {
    return result;
  }
  //no cache
  result = Promise.resolve(fn.apply(null, args)).then(
    (r) => {
      cache.resolved(key); //tell cache promise is done
      return r;
    },
    (e) => {
      cache.resolve(key); //tell cache promise is done
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
  );
  cache.set(key, result);
  return result;
};
//thunk action creators are not (...args)=>result but
//  (...args)=>(dispatch,getState)=>result
//  so here is how we group thunk actions
const createGroupedThunkAction = (thunkAction, cache) => {
  const group = createGroup(
    cache
  )((args, dispatch, getState) =>
    thunkAction.apply(null, args)(dispatch, getState)
  );

  return (...args) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    return group(args, dispatch, getState);
  };
};
//permanent memory cache store creator
const createPermanentMemoryCache = (cache = new Map()) => {
  return {
    get: (key) => cache.get(key),
    set: (key, value) => cache.set(key, value),
    resolved: (x) => x,
  };
};
const NOT_REQUESTED = { requested: false };
const initialState = { data: {} };
//action types
const BEGIN = 'BEGIN';
const SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS';
//action creators
const fetchMagazineListDetail = createGroupedThunkAction(
  (id) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
      //return a promise
      return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: BEGIN, payload: { id } });
        setTimeout(() =>
          dispatch({ type: SUCCESS, payload: { id } })
        );
      });
    };
  },
  createPermanentMemoryCache()
);

const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === BEGIN) {
    return produce(state, (draft) => {
      const { id } = payload;
      draft.data[id] = { ...state.data[id] };
      draft.data[id].loading = true;
      draft.data[id].requested = true;
    });
  }
  if (type === SUCCESS) {
    const { id } = payload;
    return produce(state, (draft) => {
      draft.data[id].loading = false;
      draft.data[id].requested = true;
      draft.data[id].result = payload;
    });
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectData = (state) => state.data;
const crateSelectDataById = (id) =>
  createSelector([selectData], (data) =>
    data[id] ? data[id] : NOT_REQUESTED
  );
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      //thunk
      ({ dispatch, getState }) => (next) => (action) => {
        if (typeof action === 'function') {
          return action(dispatch, getState);
        }
        return next(action);
      }
    )
  )
);
const Data = React.memo(function Data({ id }) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const selectDataById = useMemo(
    () => crateSelectDataById(id),
    [id]
  );
  const result = useSelector(selectDataById);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!result.requested) {
      dispatch(fetchMagazineListDetail(id));
    }
  }, [dispatch, id, result.requested]);
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2)}</pre>;
});
const App = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div>
      <select
        value={id}
        onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value={1}>1</option>
        <option value={2}>2</option>
      </select>
      <Data id={id} />
      <Data id={id} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/immer@7.0.5/dist/immer.umd.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

During one render the fetchMagazineListDetail is dispatched twice but if you check the redux dev tools you can see it is actually only dispatched once. When changing the id to an id that was used earlier you see nothing will be dispatched.

If you don't care about dispatching the actions multiple times and just want to cache responses then you can do the following:

```
const apiCall = (x) => x;
const groupedApiCall = createGroup(
  createPermanentMemoryCache()
)(apiCall);
```

You could also solve the problem in the service worker as that's what was created to cache responses.